# Change ttk.Progressbar colour without using a built in theme

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using a progressbar paired with a label to give a progressbar with a percentage that updates when given a value. I'm trying to make the progressbar change colour when it reaches certain thresholds (for now just at each quarter).

I did some reading and found that I could use ttk.Style to do this, and I have got that working. However, the issue I run into is that changing style to use a theme changes other ttk widgets in my parent UI, as it should. This isn't what I want, as I only want to change the progressbar colour. However, when I try to just create a style without using a theme, the colour of my progressbar doesn't change. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code for the widget is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class ProgressBarPercent(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, orient, length, mode):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.root = parent

        # ttk style
        self.style = ttk.Style()
##        self.style.theme_use("clam")
        self.style.configure("green.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground="green", background="green")
        self.style.configure("blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground="blue", background="blue")
        self.style.configure("yellow.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground="yellow", background="yellow")
        self.style.configure("orange.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground="orange", background="orange")
        self.style.configure("red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground="red", background="red")
        
        # Progressbar, percent label
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient = orient, 
              length = length, mode = mode, style = "orange.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        self.text.set("0%")
        self.percent = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.text)
        self.percent.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.progress.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def value(self, value):
        # Progressbar updates based on input value
        self.progress['value'] = value
        percent_value = round(value, 1)
        self.text.set(str(percent_value) + '%')
        alert = False
        if value < 25:
            self.progress.configure(style = "green.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        elif 25 <= value < 50:            
            self.progress.configure(style = "blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        elif 50 <= value < 75:            
            self.progress.configure(style = "yellow.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        elif 75 <= value <= 100:            
            self.progress.configure(style = "orange.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        elif 100 <= value:
            alert = True
            self.progress.configure(style = "red.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
        self.alert(alert)

    def alert(self, alert):
        if alert == True:
            self.percent.configure(fg = 'red')
        else:
            self.percent.configure(fg = 'black')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    progress = ProgressBarPercent(root, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL, 
                  length = 100, mode = 'determinate') 

    progress.grid()
    progress.value(67.322)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change the color, you need't 5 different new Styles. You can config one, to get different colors

```
        if value < 25:
            self.style.configure("TProgressbar", foreground="green", background="green")
        elif 25 <= value < 50:
            self.style.configure("TProgressbar", foreground="blue", background="blue")
        elif 50 <= value < 75:
            self.style.configure("TProgressbar", foreground="yellow", background="yellow")
        elif 75 <= value <= 100:
            self.style.configure("TProgressbar", foreground="orange", background="orange")
        elif 100 <= value:
            alert = True
            self.style.configure("TProgressbar", foreground="red", background="red")
```

Comment: Is it changing the color of the progressbar?

Comment: yes. color will changes. If you have 2 or more progressbars, than you need to make styles for it (if you don't want to become this style for the others). But it makes no sense, to make 5 styles for one widget. With that reason you get some trouble with your other widgets

Comment: The default theme used is ```vista``` and it doesn't change the colours

Comment: he used in his code "clam". in this doc you will read, that some options are only available with specific themes https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_progressbar.htm